# changing margin-top with Tween TimeLineLite

Tags: css, animation, margin, tween, gsap

I do have in HTML a simple DIV block with the following css :

```
#vogelhuisje {
    display: block;
    width: 320px;
    height: 380px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Now I try to add some simple animation by changing the margin-top in 5 seconds.

```
var myBannerTimeline = new TimelineLite();
myBannerTimeline.from('#vogelhuisje', 5, {css:{marginTop:400}, ease:Bounce.easeOut});
```

But it does not work. Any idea what I am doing wrong?
With an absolute top and left I can make this work, but wants the website responsive and as such the div always in the center with margins.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a codepen example of your code working:

http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/njxuz

Make sure you are using the latest GSAP version from CDN. At the time of this writing the version is **1.13.2**

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.13.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you could also add `position:relative;` to your `#vogelhuisje` element. But note, that animations will perform better cross-browser when you use position `absolute`, so it takes the element out of the flow of the document.

Also since you are animating `margin-top`, you could add `autoRound:false` to your CSS object in your `to()` tween, so `margin-top` doesn't animate on a sub-pixel level.

```
var myBannerTimeline = new TimelineLite();
myBannerTimeline.from('#vogelhuisje', 5, {css:{marginTop:400,autoRound:false}, ease:Bounce.easeOut});
```

Reference for `autoRound` is at:

[GSAP CSSPlugin Docs](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/Plugins/CSSPlugin/).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Want to change this css it will increase second percentage, 
background-position-x: calc(100% - 30%)
background-position-x: calc(100% - 40%)
background-position-x: calc(100% - 50%)




How can I ?